# Позиватися НА чи ДО когось?

Tags: прийменники, керування-відмінками

Власне, легко знайти, що позиваються ДО суду, але в словниках нема прикладів саме в контексті позиватися ДО/НА людину/організацію/установу, яка щось порушує.

P. S. Підкажіть, будь ласка, український словник з дієслівного керування, просто змучилася вже від таких питань) Дякую завчасно)

Answer (score 2):

Ось стаття [ЯКЩО ПОЗИВАТИСЯ, ТО ЯК?](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/37130/33-Gorodenska4.pdf?sequence=1) [Катерини Городенської](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> В одному з видань читаємо: *Він позивається **на нотаріуса***, в іншому — **до
> президента**, у третьому — **проти організаторів**. Пор.: *Юристи радять
> письмово звернутися до нотаріуса для посвідчення договору, отримати
> відмову і **позиватися на нотаріуса** до суду* (Юридичний радник);
> *Попередній уряд навіть доручив Мін’юсту **позиватися до президента** з
> приводу «прихватизації» майже півтори сотні гектарів землі, цікавої
> для археологів* (Україна молода, 8.04.2010); *Сьогодні ці українці
> готові **позиватися проти організаторів** виборчого процесу і держави
> загалом* (Українська правда, 25.02.2010). Мимоволі задумуєшся, чи
> рівноправні для дієслова позиватися ці прийменниково-відмінкові форми,
> що називають відповідача? У професійному вжитку, тобто в судочинстві,
> узвичаєні дві основні прийменниково-відмінкові форми: ***позиватися на**
> кого-небудь і **позиватися до** кого-небудь.* Проте вони розрізняються
> значеннями своїх іменників: прийменник на поєднується переважно з
> іменниками — назвами осіб, прийменник до, крім цих назв, може
> сполучатися з назвами держави, якоїсь структури, установи тощо: *У разі
> недотримання умов кредитного договору Спілка має право **позиватися на
> позичальника** до суду..; Румунія збирається **позиватися до України**; АНТК
> імені Антонова **позивається до Фонду** держмайна через арешт АН-124.*
> Форма проти кого-небудь із дієсловом позиватися трапляється зрідка,
> здебільшого в непрофесійному вжитку.
>
> Можлива ще одна
> прийменниково-відмінкова форма зі значенням відповідача — ***з
> ким-небудь***, але за умови, що дієслово позиватися виражає значення —
> ‘мати з ким-небудь судову справу, тривалий час судитися’: *Він*
> [шляхтич] *мав діло в волость, **позивався** за млин **з** своїми **спільниками**,
> власниками того млина* (І. Нечуй-Левицький); — *Пан Стадницький знову
> **позивається з лісовиками*** (М. Стельмах).
>
> Є кілька прийменниково-відмінкових форм, що вказують на причину, привід
> для позивання. Найпоширенішими з-поміж них є форми з первинними
> прийменниками *за, через* та похідним книжним прийменником *з приводу: Це
> колись було, що знав тільки сусід сусіда та й то, коли **позивалися за
> межу*** (Ю. Яновський); *Це брат його, Перс на ймення, з яким після смерті
> батька Гесіод **почав позиватися за спадщину**; Польща не має наміру
> **позиватися** до України через ненадходження російського газу; Громадяни
> України не можуть **позиватися** до Росії **з приводу повернення** їх
> заощаджень СРСР.*
>
> Отже, форми, уживані з дієсловом *позиватися* для
> означення особи відповідача, розрізняються обсягом значень іменників
> та сферами свого побутування: в офіційному професійному вжитку
> переважають форми *на кого-небудь* і *до кого-небудь*, у непрофесійному —
> *проти кого-небудь*. Прийменникововідмінкові форми, що визначають
> причину позивання, так само неоднакові за своїм стилістичним
> використанням: не мають обмежень форми з прийменниками *за* і *через*,
> книжне забарвлення властиве формі з прийменником з *приводу*.

Comment: Дякую щиро!) А чи можете порадити якийсь словник з керування?

Comment: @bekasita як словниками я намагаюсь користуватись [r2u.org.ua](https://r2u.org.ua/) та [e2u.org.ua](https://e2u.org.ua/)

Comment: Тобто, позиватися до установи (або до повноважної організації) на/проти відповідача. Або мати спільний з іншою стороною позов/спірку.

Answer (score -1):

Згідно з [Академічним тлумачним словником (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/), позиваються не *на* і не *до* когось, а [*з* кимось](http://sum.in.ua/s/zghidno):

**//** з ким. Мати з ким-небудь судову справу. Цур йому з дужим бороться, а з багатим позиваться! (Номис, 1864, № 1099); — Пан Стадницький знову позивається з лісовиками. Ще мало йому землі. У рік волі заховав од нас його батько золоту грамоту, а син хоче зовсім старцями поробити людей (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 272);

Comment: Прийменник "з" тут вживаний у значенні "спільно з іншою стороною".

Comment: Ви вважаєте, що "він" та "багатий" у "Цур йому з дужим бороться, а з багатим позиваться!" разом подають позов проти якоїсь третьої сторони? Ну я навіть не знаю, що вам сказати.

Comment: Ні, ви не вірно зрозуміли. Якщо ви позиваєтесь на когось до суду, то існує також інша сторона (відповідач), яка також висуває до вас зустрічне звинувачення і ви маєте між собою не вирішену спірку. "Позиватися з багатим" - мати не вирішену з ним спаву в суді. Ви можете доповнити в покращити свою відповідь.